# segmentation fault (core dumped) C lang

Tags: c

the program asks for a money amount and prints the number of 500 & 100 bills its made of

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){



  int no500,no100,amount;

  printf("please enter amount to withdraw :");
  scanf("%d",amount);
  void function(int a,int*x, int*y){
   *x= a/500;
   *y=(a%500)/100;

}
  function(amount,&no500,&no100);
 printf("the number of 500 bills  %d\n ",no500);
printf("the number of 100 bills  %d\n ",no100);


}
```

when i run i get :

please enter amount to withdraw :1500

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: `scanf("%d",amount);`is wrong, google how to use `scanf`.

Comment: Don't use nested functions, it's an extension in some compilers and not standard.

Comment: I'm sure the answer to this question is addressed in chapter 1 of the beginner level C book you are using.

Comment: It's strange how many do not see the problem with passing a var that requires modifying by value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scanf()` expects pointers as parameter. Note the `&` to pass the *address* of `amount`, not its value.

```
scanf( "%d", &amount );
```

Your program takes the *value* of `amount` (which has not been initialized), and writes the number you entered to that value interpreted as a memory address -- which is an invalid access, making the program crash.

In olden times, memory protection was done via "segments", and a faulty memory access resulted in a "segmentation fault". The error message has survived. The contents of core memory -- i.e. the program in its current state -- have been dumped to disk (in a file named "core"). This can be used for debugging. This dumping is optional, and (on Unix) controlled via `ulimit -c`, so you might also see the Segfault *without* the "(core dumped)" part. (And "core memory" is another anachronism just like "segmentation fault".)

Enabling relevant compiler warnings should have warned you about the uninitalized use of `amount`, and possibly even the type mismatch in the call to `scanf()`.

Also, you *should* check the return value of `scanf()` to make sure it actually succeeded, or `amout` will *still* be uninitialized (e.g. when the user entered letters instead of a number).

Answer (score 0):

You missed `&` in

```
scanf("%d",amount);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &amount);
//----------^
```